# Prompt during the installation of a Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to prompt the administrator during the installation of a Wordpress plugin.

I would like the administrator to set parameters that will be used in the next part of the installation.

Do you know how to do that ? Do you have any clue ?

Thank you.

Comment: I' afraid you'll have to do a basic install of a plugin, including at least admin page where will user be able to enter another params and submit them to the next install part. This might not be the best solution from UX point of view, but is manageble in the WordPress environment...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do a prompt for the installation is to create 2 plugins, one for the installation and configuration of the "framework" of the plugin and the other for the use of the framework.

The "installation" function in wordpress doesn't show you anything, it's launched in back-end.